# What is the name of a Function\Method whose success\failure is not necessary for successful execution?

Tags: coding-style

Evening,

Is there a common or standardised name given to a function or method whose execution is not crucial or necessary for the successful execution of a program? Whether the function fails or succeeds in its purpose is not important, only that it was attempted.

I've been naming such functions as "volatile" (e.g. `volatileInsertSearchLog()`), as they're not always expected to succeed, but still may return a value for error reporting purposes. I was curious to see whether there was a more suitable name?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a 'Try' prefix and maybe have it return a boolean, which would be true on success, and false on failure. So something like:

`bool TryInsertSearchLog()`

The .NET framework uses this for parsing, for example `bool Int32.TryParse(string, out int)`

Comment: I never liked using the word "try" in function names because of try-catch blocks, but this definitely makes sense.